# How do I check storage size for a Knative container and how can I increase it?

Tags: knative, knative-serving

I have few storage related question for Knative apps

1. How do I check how much storage space do I have for a stateless knative apps.
   Reason being I need the Knative pod to process a huge file of 1G before removing it. it seem to get problem processing a large file. I am suspecting storage size causing the issue.
2. How do I increase the knative app disk size if it is possible?

Not sure how kubernetes allocate disk space for a container.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Knative uses the underlying container filesystem to store scratch files.

For an ordinary Kubernetes installation, those will be a series of overlay directories on local disk, but it's possible that some or all of the overlay directories are mounted on `tmpfs`. Depending on your cluster, you may be able to raise your `requests` and `limits` to get more RAM.

On Google's Cloud Run, [disk storage is backed by RAM](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tips/general#deleting_temporary_files). Requesting more memory might help here, or streaming the file over the network piece by piece. If it's always the same file, you can build it into your container image.